# XCConfig syntax

Tags: ios, xcode, xcconfig

If I had an `Adhoc.xcconfig` where I defined a variable:

```
PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = IS_ADHOC=1 CRASHLYTICS=1
```

and in a run script, there's a check that looks like:

```
if [ "${PREPROCESSOR_DEFINTIONS/CRASHLYTICS=1}" = "$PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" ] ; then
    echo "Crashlytics is disabled, skipping Crashlytics dSYM upload"
else
    echo "Crashlytics is on"
end
```

What does that if statement check? I'm unclear if the `/` is syntax specific to bash or to xcconfig. What's also confusing is that the if statement is checking the result of an assignment using `=` not `==`.

Breaking down the if statement piece by piece:

- `"${PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}/CRASHLYTICS=1}"` - is a variable expansion.
- `/` - is this indexing the larger variable, `PREPROCESSOR_DEFINTIONS` to check for the existence of the `CRASHLYTICS` variable?
- `= "$PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS"` - Is this just assigning this string literal to the result of the prior expression?

Anyone that could illuminate that syntax and what the if statement is trying to accomplish, that would be great.

Comment: Where is the run script from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about `bash`, not xcconfig files. The `xcconfig` file only establishes a build setting. By default, build settings are exported to run-script build phases as environment variables. That's the only relationship between the two. The format of xcconfig files was only relevant while reading the xcconfig file.

From the `bash` man page section on Parameter Expansion:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.   *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced  with  *string*. […] If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the / following *pattern* may be  omitted. […]

So, `"${PREPROCESSOR_DEFINTIONS/CRASHLYTICS=1}"` expands `PREPROCESSOR_DEFINTIONS` but removes all instances of `CRASHLYTICS=1` from the resulting string.

The single `=` is not assignment. It's the equals comparison. Bash also supports `==` but, as the man page says:

> `=` may be used in place of `==` for strict POSIX compliance.

So, technically, `=` is the more standard.

Thus, the `if` is testing if `PREPROCESSOR_DEFINTIONS` **doesn't contain** `CRASHLYTICS=1`. If it did contain it, then the expansion with `CRASHLYTICS=1` removed would not equal the unmodified expansion.

Of course, this makes sense given the `echo` statements in each branch of the `if`.

Comment: Ah thank you! I was trying to understand some legacy code in a project I'm on. That makes a ton of sense now, great answer.